# Async SerialPort Wrapper

Tags: c#, async-await, serial-port

I've been working with the `SerialPort` class for a while, trying to figure out the best way to work with it, and especially adding support for Async-Await in C#. I also started before 4.5, so I didn't have access to the `BaseStream` member (so no `BaseStream.ReadAsync()`). I wanted to get some opinions on it before I started relying on it too heavily. Performance considerations and stability are high priority, but also figuring out if I'm reinventing the wheel.

The code is designed to wrap around a `SerialPort` to provide Async-Await operations. It does this by intercepting calls to Write and the `SerialPort.DataRecieved` events and relaying the data to a pair of Reactive Subjects that client code can subscribe to. Note this code requires the nuget package Rx-Main.

```
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;
namespace Core.IO {
    public sealed class ComPort : IDisposable, INotifyPropertyChanged{ 
        private Subject<byte[]> _txDataSubject;
        private Subject<byte[]> _rxDataSubject;
        private SerialPort _port;

        public String PortName {
            get {
                return _port.PortName;
            }
            set {
                _port.PortName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("PortName");
                RaisePropertyChanged("IsOpen");
            }
        }
        public Boolean IsOpen {
            get {
                return _port.IsOpen;
            }
        }
        public IObservable<byte[]> DataTx {
            get {
                return _txDataSubject.AsObservable();
            }
        }
        public IObservable<byte[]> DataRx {
            get {
                return _rxDataSubject.AsObservable();
            }
        }
        public ComPort() {
            _port = new SerialPort();
            _txDataSubject = new Subject<byte[]>();
            _rxDataSubject = new Subject<byte[]>();
            _port.DataReceived+=(sender,args)=>{
#if DEBUG
                Console.WriteLine("({0}) RX on thread {1}",PortName, System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
#endif
                _rxDataSubject.OnNext(_port.Encoding.GetBytes(_port.ReadExisting()));
            };
        }
        public void Open() {
            _port.Open();
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsOpen");
        }
        public void Close() {
            _port.Close();
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsOpen");
        }
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public Boolean IsDisposed {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public void Write(string data) {
            _txDataSubject.OnNext(_port.Encoding.GetBytes(data));
            _port.Write(data);
        }
        private void Dispose(bool isDisposing) {
            if (IsDisposed) return;
            if (isDisposing) {
                _port.Dispose();
                _txDataSubject.Dispose();
            }
            IsDisposed = true;
        }
        public void Dispose() {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
        ~ComPort() {
            Dispose(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Right now, your post only contains code. Please add more context explaining what your code does and what you want reviewed.

Comment: Is that enough?

Answer (score 3):

```
_port.Encoding.GetBytes(_port.ReadExisting())
```

If you want to work with `byte[]`, then your data should never appear as `string`, even temporarily, because some byte sequences are likely going to be invalid in your encoding.

I believe you should be able to use [the `byte[]` overload of `Read()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143549) for this. (Though switching to `byte[]` and `async` methods of the `BaseStream` is probably a better choice in the long run.)

---

Your class is schizophrenic about whether it wants to use `string` or `byte[]` (the observables use `byte[]`, `Write()` uses `string`). You should figure out which choice makes more sense and stick to it.

---

What is the purpose of `DataTx`? I think that being able to read what you have written is not commonly needed.

---

I realize that Tx and Rx are abbreviations used in networking, but I find them confusing. Are you sure users of this library will immediately understand them? If not, you should rename the properties.

---

```
Boolean
String
```

It's common to write those types in their keyword form: `bool`, `string`.

---

```
~ComPort() {
    Dispose(false);
}
```

You don't have any unmanaged resources, so `Dispose(false)` basically doesn't do anything. But this means there is no reason for this class to have a finalizer.

[The Dispose Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e) makes sense when you're writing a class that is going to be inherited. But since your class is `sealed` (nice, most people don't bother with that), I think there is also no reason to have the `Dispose(bool)` overload, just a single `Dispose()` method will be enough.

Comment: The `SerialPort.ReadExisting` method returns a string. I'd like to use the normal `SerialPort.Read(byte[],....)' method, but I've read that the `BytesToRead` property is unreliable, meaning I either have to allocate a large buffer to get everything, wasting memory and probably time, or I risk loosing data, which is unacceptable. I should be able to guarantee that the encoding is at LEAST UTF8, but you're right, that's a major issue.

Comment: The class isn't so much schizophrenic as incomplete. I wanted it to work with byte[]'s internally but provide shortcuts for string, since this is the most common method of in and out.

Comment: `DataTx` is there because I need the ability to log both input and output from the port. Making the port itself the point of access for this information seemed logical.

Comment: I'm currently the only one using the library, but I think the standard abbriviations for Transmit and Recieve are well known enough to deal with for most people. If I get more feedback saying their confusing I might change it.

Comment: The full dispose pattern was implemented basically to get VS to stop yelling at me about it. I'll change that.